# mapStateToProps makes props.{variable} undefined after state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning React with Redux and came across this issue where there are two connected components - AvengerTable (Table) and AvengerTableRow (Row).

The `AvengerTableRow` Components are used inside the `AvengerTableRow`. I `mapStateToProps` in the `AvengerTable` and pass a piece of that state to each `AvengerTableRow` component. Inside the `AvengerTableRow` , I dispatch an action to change the value of that particular r. But now, for some reason, the props inside my `AvengerTable` Component loses its state mapped by `mapStateToProps` and it becomes undefined.

I am actually changing part of that state inside my reducer so I thought it might not call render again. So I tried to return the new state as well. But even, the props becomes undefined.

**AvengerTable Component:**

```
    render() {
            const tableRows = this.props.avengers.map(avenger => (
                <AvengerTableRow key={avenger.id} avenger={avenger} />)
            )

            return (
                <div><h2>Avengers List</h2>
                    <table className="table table-sm table-hover">
                        <thead className="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Avenger Name</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {tableRows}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )
        }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return { avengers: state.homeReducer.avengers }
    };
```

**AvengerTableRow Component:**

```
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.editable ? <input className="form-control" onChange={e => this.editChangeHandler(e, 'name')}
                    defaultValue={this.state.avenger.name} /> : this.state.avenger.name}</td>
                <td>{this.state.editable ? <input className="form-control" onChange={e => this.editChangeHandler(e, 'avengername')}
                    defaultValue={this.state.avenger.avengername} /> : this.state.avenger.avengername}</td>
                <td>
                    {this.state.editable ? <button onClick={this.saveAvenger} className="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button> :
                        <button onClick={this.editContent} className="btn btn-sm btn-default">Edit</button>
                    }
                    &nbsp;
                    {this.state.editable ? <button onClick={this.cancelEdit} className="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cancel</button> :
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

saveAvenger(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.editAvenger(this.state.avenger);
    this.setState({
        originalAvenger: { ...this.state.avenger }
    });
    this.editContent();
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ editAvenger: avenger => dispatch(editAvenger(avenger)) })
```

**Reducer:**

```
......
case homeActionTypes.EDIT_AVENGER: {
    return state.avengers.map(avenger =>
        avenger.id == action.payload.id ? ({ ...avenger, name: action.payload.name, avengername: action.payload.avengername }) : avenger)
}
......
```

After the dispatch in AvengerTableRow is finished, my props in AvengerTable looks like this:

```
​{
   avengers: undefined,
   dispatch: function dispatch(),
   __proto__: Object { … }
}
```

Please help me with understanding

1. Why my props `avengers` inside `props` becomes undefined even though
   the state is being returned in the reducer.
2. Also even if dispatch does not run asynchronously, why does the props lose its state set in the previous render ?
3. Even if `connect` does not detect a change in the state due to shallow changes on state, why does it lose its already mapped state to props ?

Comment: you must update avengers inside the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return updated array from store you need to update in your state not directly that you done so far.

```
case homeActionTypes.EDIT_AVENGER: {
        return {...state , avengers : state.avengers.map(avenger =>
            avenger.id == action.payload.id ? ({ ...avenger, name: action.payload.name, avengername: action.payload.avengername }) : avenger)
    }
    }
```

Comment: yes now the props are loaded. I have added the store to the window object for debugging from the browser console. After I mutate the state, I could not find the state updated in the store when I do `store.getState()`. Is it not supposed or should it be updated?

Comment: @v1shnu have you check your component showing updated state ?

Comment: yes.. the component is showing updated state now. But why does the state returned by `store.getState()` is not updated ?

Comment: you can check in console log of redux middle ware log all state updates.. you will get clear picture of store updation

Comment: hmm ok.. Thanks for helping out. Can you please edit your answer with some explanation so that I can accept your answer.